# Meteor App - 3 Rows from MongoDB is not displaying on Browser

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What wrong with this code? 
The 3 rows from mongoDB wont display on browser. 
Please help.

[My Short Meteor Code](http://i62.tinypic.com/11kz6s7.png)

Really cant find what's wrong.

---

```
<head>
  <title>Things to do.</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Our List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

---

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
  db.tasks.find()
2015-08-14T08:27:44.644+0000 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:8081 (127.0.0.1) failed
2015-08-14T08:27:44.644+0000 reconnect 127.0.0.1:8081 (127.0.0.1) ok
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55cd9d2456b678da6dcaa972"), "text" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-08-14T07:47:48.586Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55cd9e2b56b678da6dcaa975"), "text" : "Eat out!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-08-14T07:52:11.635Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55cd9e3e56b678da6dcaa976"), "text" : "Tour around the world.", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-08-14T07:52:30.944Z") }
```

There it is, my code in pure text.

Comment: show some code you have written.

Comment: One of the reasons why you need to have a certain reputation score before you post images is because we want you to post the "text" of your code, and not a screenshot.. Please [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32005947/edit) your post and copy and past the code as text. Highlight it and press "Ctrl+K" to indent it nicely as "code" being distinquished from the rest of the text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that could go wrong:

- Your `Tasks` collection may not be [published](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe). Make sure you still have the `autopublish` package installed in your app, or publish and subscribe to your collection following [this tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe).
- You are not using the same Mongodb database as your app's: make sure by printing the app's `MONGO_URL`.

In your js file:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);
}
```

Comment: im a total noob, this is my first tutorial. I am only following this....  https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections . Sir, where do i paste your code?

Comment: Whoops, my bad, turns out `<body>` does match `Template.body` after all... Did not know that.

Comment: When you type `meteor list` in the terminal, do you see the `autopublish` package in the list?

Comment: meteor-platform  1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app

Comment: okay, then autopublish is not installed, so your Collection's data cannot be retrieved by your client. Try installing `autopublish` using `meteor add autopublish` and open your app again.

Comment: It worked! After meteor add autopublish, the 3 rows displayed on browser. Thank you very much @BraveKenny !

Comment: Here's the successful screenshot    http://s14.postimg.org/62xy1tdi9/Screenshot_2015_08_14_at_6_38_58_PM.png